# Typing attributed text with imags in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, uitextview, chat

I'm working on chat application where I was not able to resolve with this requirement.
I need to enter text with custom images(emojis) as input, but not sure how to do it.

I did some R&D over the internet but didn't helped the implementation.
Please someone provide snippet how to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Please post your code so we can help solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// create an NSMutableAttributedString that we'll append everything to
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Start of text")

// create our NSTextAttachment
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "awesomeIcon.png")

// wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

// add the NSTextAttachment wrapper to our full string, then add some more text.
fullString.append(image1String)
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

// draw the result in a label
yourLabel.attributedText = fullString
```